# What to do when Active Directory and IIS server are not in same domain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I developed an application in ASP NET MVC. The application uses AD to authenticate user. It works fine in development . But when the application is hosted in IIS, It can not validate AD user. Note that, AD and IIS are not in same domain.

Comment: When published in IIS, It shows user or password is incorrect even after exact user and password is given .

Comment: When you say that it "uses AD to authenticate", do you mean IIS is setup to use Windows Authentication? Or does the user provide their username and password and you authenticate them in your code?

Comment: Users provide their user name and password, I verify whether the given credentials are that of active directory .

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you use to do that? It's likely a simple update.